# Don't see any input command in selenium for Input Tag-based DevExpress Dropdown Editor

Tags: java, selenium, devexpress

I have an element that looks like combo box ( DevEx control ). Its Tag is input and not Select. Hence Select command does not work. I can locate that element and when send a click command, it opens the list. However, I am not able to select any Value from it.

Code snippet using firebug is as follows:

```
input id="ctl00_MainContent_tbc_UserRights_tbpnl_UserInfo_ddl_Company_I" class="dxeEditArea dxeEditAreaSys" type="text" style="cursor:default;" onchange="aspxETextChanged('ctl00_MainContent_tbc_UserRights_tbpnl_UserInfo_ddl_Company')" readonly="readonly" name="ctl00$MainContent$tbc_UserRights$tbpnl_UserInfo$ddl_Company" autocomplete="off" tabindex="14" onfocus="aspxEGotFocus('ctl00_MainContent_tbc_UserRights_tbpnl_UserInfo_ddl_Company')" onblur="aspxELostFocus('ctl00_MainContent_tbc_UserRights_tbpnl_UserInfo_ddl_Company'
```

Selenium Code is as Follows

```
WebElement companydropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_MainContent_tbc_UserRights_tbpnl_UserInfo_ddl_Company_I")); Select Clickthis1 = new Select (companydropdown); clickThis.selectByVisibleText("Multi National Retail Group");
```

error is as follows

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "input" Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '32a636c', time: '2015-03-05 22:01:35' System info: host: 'ct-113', ip: '172.24.1.248', os.name: 'Windows XP', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '5.1', java.version: '1.8.0_45' Driver info: driver.version: unknown at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select.(Select.java:46) at MyPackage.MyClass.main(MyClass``.java:113)

Answer (score 0):

Your drop down list is being simulated by JavaScript. It's probably a DIV (or maybe a SELECT or TABLE) after clicking the input, so you will need to locate that new element after clicking the input.

There's no built in command. You may need to FindElement(By.CssPath("table[id*=ddl_Company] td:contains(Default Company)")) and click it

Comment: <table id="ctl00_MainContent_tbc_UserRights_tbpnl_UserInfo_ddl_Company_DDD_L_LBT" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;border-collapse:separate;">
              <tr class="dxeListBoxItemRow">
               <td class="dxeListBoxItem">---Select Company---</td>
              </tr><tr class="dxeListBoxItemRow">
               <td class="dxeListBoxItem">Default Company</td>
              </tr><tr class="dxeListBoxItemRow">
               <td class="dxeListBoxItem">Multi National Retail &nbsp;Group</td>
              </tr>
             </table>

Comment: Is there a way doing it.Just for your info.....when seen the source the list items are shown  as above

Comment: There's no built in command. You may need to FindElement(By.CssPath("table[id*=ddl_Company] td:contains(Default Company)")) and click it

Answer (score 0):

Please see below code snippet, I have written in c# but you can take this reference for any language. 
Basic idea is to design logic to select elements from dropdown by using *FindElement* and *FindElements*.

Extension Method of *`IWebDriver`*

```
public static class SeleniumExtension
{
        public static void SelectDropDownByText(this IWebDriver driver, string clickId, string tableId, string visibleText)
        {
            //Click on dropdown element to see dropdown options
            driver.FindElement(By.Id(clickId)).Click();

            //Get all rows from the table(dropdown options table) by tableId
            var trElements = driver.FindElement(By.Id(tableId)).FindElements(By.CssSelector("tr"));1
            //Go to row by row
            foreach(var trElement in trElements)
            {
                //Select celll(td) of the row
                var tdElement = trElement.FindElement(By.CssSelector("td"));

                //Scoll to that td so we can select the td
                Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
                actions.MoveToElement(tdElement);
                actions.Perform();

                //CHeck td text if td text is equal to given text then click that td
                if (tdElement.Text.Trim() == visibleText.Trim())
                {
                    //Select td/dropdown option
                    tdElement.Click();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Limitations:-

- The dropdown items should not have duplicate text elements
- Just found one way to select it by visible text, not by Id or Value

**Code example :** 
Web page source code

```
<td width="55%" valign="top" align="left">
   <table class="dxeButtonEdit inputBox" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" id="EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs" style="width:150px;">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td style="display:none;"><input id="EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs_VI" name="EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs_VI" type="hidden" value="AAAA"></td>
            <td class="dxic" onmousedown="return aspxDDDropDown('EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs', event)" style="width:100%;padding-left:1px;padding-right:1px;padding-top:1px;padding-bottom:1px;"><input class="dxeEditArea dxeEditAreaSys" id="EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs_I" name="EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs" onfocus="aspxEGotFocus('EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs')" onblur="aspxELostFocus('EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs')" onchange="aspxETextChanged('EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs')" onkeydown="aspxEKeyDown('EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs', event)" value="Parmnad(AAAA)" type="text" style="height:15px;" autocomplete="off"></td>
            <td id="EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs_B-1" class="dxeButtonEditButton" onmousedown="return aspxDDDropDown('EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs', event)" style="-khtml-user-select:none;">
               <table class="dxbebt" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-collapse:separate;">
                  <tbody>
                     <tr>
                        <td class="dx"><img id="EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs_B-1Img" class="dxEditors_edtDropDown" src="/DXR.axd?r=1_5-7rgYm" alt="v"></td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <input type="hidden" id="EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs_DDDWS" name="EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs_DDDWS" value="0:0:-1:-10000:-10000:0:-10000:-10000:1">
   <div id="EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs_DDD_PW-1" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;z-index:10000;visibility:hidden;display:none;">
      <table id="EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs_DDD_PWST-1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-collapse:separate;position:relative;">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td onmousedown="aspxPWMDown(event,'EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs_DDD',-1,false)" style="width:200px;cursor:default;">
                  <table id="EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs_DDD_CLW-1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:200px;border-collapse:collapse;border-collapse:separate;">
                     <tbody>
                        <tr>
                           <td id="EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs_DDD_PWC-1" style="height:100%;">
                              <div id="EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs_DDD_CSD-1">
                                 <input type="hidden" id="EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs_DDD_LDeletedItems" name="EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs_DDD_LDeletedItems" value=""><input type="hidden" id="EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs_DDD_LInsertedItems" name="EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs_DDD_LInsertedItems" value=""><input type="hidden" id="EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs_DDD_LCustomCallback" name="EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs_DDD_LCustomCallback" value="">
                                 <table class="dxeListBox" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs_DDD_L" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-collapse:separate;">
                                    <tbody>
                                       <tr>
                                          <td valign="top">
                                             <div id="EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs_DDD_L_D" class="dxlbd" style="width:100%;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:auto;">
                                                <input id="EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs_DDD_L_VI" type="hidden" name="EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs$DDD$L" value="AAAA">
                                                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-collapse:separate;visibility:hidden!important;display:none!important;">
                                                   <tbody>
                                                      <tr id="EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs_DDD_L_LBI-1" class="dxeListBoxItemRow">
                                                         <td id="EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs_DDD_L_LBI-1T0" class="dxeListBoxItem">&nbsp;</td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                   </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                                <div id="EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs_DDD_L_TS" style="display: none;">
                                                </div>
                                                <table id="EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs_DDD_L_LBT" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;border-collapse:separate;">
                                                   <tbody>
                                                      <tr class="dxeListBoxItemRow">
                                                         <td class="dxeListBoxItem" id="EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs_DDD_L_LBI0T0">Select One</td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                      <tr class="dxeListBoxItemRow">
                                                         <td class="dxeListBoxItem" id="EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs_DDD_L_LBI1T0">Macccc Dongle</td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                      <tr class="dxeListBoxItemRow">
                                                         <td class="dxeListBoxItem" id="EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs_DDD_L_LBI2T0">Rock Start</td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                      <tr class="dxeListBoxItemRow">
                                                         <td class="dxeListBoxItem" id="EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs_DDD_L_LBI3T0">Alliau babbaa</td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                      <tr class="dxeListBoxItemRow">
                                                         <td class="dxeListBoxItem" id="EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs_DDD_L_LBI4T0">Mong star audomma</td>
                                                      </tr>
                                                   </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                                <div id="EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs_DDD_L_BS" style="display: none;">
                                                </div>
                                             </div>
                                          </td>
                                       </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                 </table>
                                 <script id="dxss_1356993039" type="text/javascript">
                                    <!--
                                    aspxAddDisabledItems('EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs_DDD_L',[[['dxeDisabled'],[''],['']]]);
                                    
                                    var dxo = new ASPxClientListBox('EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs_DDD_L');
                                    window['EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs_DDD_L'] = dxo;
                                    dxo.uniqueID = 'EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs$DDD$L';
                                    dxo.SelectedIndexChanged.AddHandler(function (s, e) { aspxCBLBSelectedIndexChanged('EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs', e); });
                                    dxo.ItemClick.AddHandler(function (s, e) { aspxCBLBItemMouseUp('EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs', e); });
                                    dxo.RequireStyleDecoration();
                                    dxo.styleDecoration.AddStyle('F','dxeFocused','');
                                    dxo.savedSelectedIndex = 9;
                                    dxo.itemsValue=['','SFIRTH','TANDE142','BBECK12','KBELLEGH','NBISSON','EBOLDUC','GBORSCHK','GBRISCOE','AAAA','PCAMERON','DCANTAGA','RCARROL2','SCAUVEL','GCAVE1','KCHRIST2','DCOLAPRE','HCUSHMAN','TDENNING','RDERHODG','ADUCHARM','REATON','TERB','MFARLEY4','EFERRELL','DFORTUNA','CFRADET','GGIOVINA','BGOLDBER','BGOODMA1','RGRAMADA','JGUBERNE','JHARTFO2','MHERNIAK','MHORNE3','MHUGGIN1','CHUNT21','JINTRAVA','PJANSEN1','RKANTAUT','DKELLETT','WKIRK1','LKOZMA','VKUSUMAK','RLAURILA','JLEACH1','KLEBLANC','FLEE2','BLESSARD','JMCCAMON','AMCCORM2','TNISSEN','JOLOMAN','EPAHAPI1','APETRIE1','ZRACZ','MRONAN','WROWE2','PROY','TSAVONI','JSNYDER5','LSTIERS','KSTRONG1','GTAIARIO','JTJONG','DTOTTEN','MTRENK1','CTURGEON','JVELLING','PWALWORT','WWELACKY','EWEST2','BWHITE7','SWHITEHE','BWILLI15','DWILLIA3','GWOOD5','KWOODBRI','MYETHON'];
                                    dxo.isSyncEnabled = false;
                                    dxo.isComboBoxList = true;
                                    dxo.hasSampleItem = true;
                                    dxo.isCallbackMode = true;
                                    dxo.callbackPageSize = 100;
                                    dxo.hoverClasses=['dxeListBoxItemHover'];
                                    dxo.selectedClasses=['dxeListBoxItemSelected'];
                                    dxo.disabledClasses=['dxeDisabled'];
                                    dxo.InlineInitialize();
                                    
                                    //-->
                                 </script>
                              </div>
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                     </tbody>
                  </table>
               </td>
               <td style="background:url('/DXR.axd?r=1_25-7rgYm') no-repeat left top;"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td style="background:url('/DXR.axd?r=1_24-7rgYm') no-repeat left top;"></td>
               <td style="background:url('/DXR.axd?r=1_26-7rgYm') no-repeat left top;">
                  <div style="height:5px;width:5px;">
                  </div>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
   <script id="dxss_452203440" type="text/javascript">
      <!--
      
      var dxo = new ASPxClientPopupControl('EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs_DDD');
      window['EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs_DDD'] = dxo;
      dxo.uniqueID = 'EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs$DDD';
      dxo.Shown.AddHandler(function (s, e) { aspxDDBPCShown('EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs', e); });
      dxo.adjustInnerControlsSizeOnShow=false;
      dxo.closeAction='CloseButton';
      dxo.popupHorizontalAlign='LeftSides';
      dxo.popupVerticalAlign='Below';
      dxo.width=0;
      dxo.height=0;
      dxo.InlineInitialize();
      
      //-->
   </script>
   <table id="EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs_LP" class="dxeLoadingPanel" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;left:0px;top:0px;z-index:30000;display:none;">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td class="dx" style="padding-right:8px;"><img src="/DXR.axd?r=2_24-7rgYm" alt="" align="middle"></td>
            <td class="dx" style="padding-left:0px;">Loading…</td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
   <div id="EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs_LD" class="dxeLoadingDiv" style="left:0px;top:0px;z-index:29999;display:none;position:absolute;">
   </div>
   <script id="dxss_1042248493" type="text/javascript">
      <!--
      aspxAddHoverItems('EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs',[[['dxeButtonEditButtonHover'],[''],['B-1'],,[['']],['Img']]]);
      aspxAddPressedItems('EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs',[[['dxeButtonEditButtonPressed'],[''],['B-1'],,[['']],['Img']]]);
      aspxAddDisabledItems('EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs',[[['dxeDisabled'],[''],['','I']],[['dxeDisabled dxeButtonDisabled'],[''],['B-1'],,[[{'spriteCssClass':'dxEditors_edtDropDownDisabled'}]],['Img']]]);
      document.getElementById("EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs_I").setAttribute("autocomplete", "off");
      
      var dxo = new MVCxClientComboBox('EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs');
      window['EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs'] = dxo;
      dxo.callBack = function(arg) { ; };
      dxo.RequireStyleDecoration();
      dxo.styleDecoration.AddStyle('F','dxeFocused','');
      dxo.incrementalFilteringMode='StartsWith';
      dxo.isCallbackMode = true;
      dxo.lastSuccessValue = 'AAAAA';
      dxo.islastSuccessValueInit = true;
      dxo.unobtrusiveValidationAttributes=eval(({'data-val-required':'Required','data-val':'true'}));
      dxo.callbackUrl="/en-US/Orders/EnterOrder/ReportsToProf";
      dxo.InlineInitialize();
      
      //-->
   </script>
   <span class="commentText">*</span>
   <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</td>
```

**Selenium code to handle this complex dropdown selection** 
_driver is a variable of IWebDriver before use you have to initiate it e.g `IWebDriver _driver = new ChromeDriver();`

```
_driver.SelectDropDownByText(
                clickId:"EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs_B-1",
                tableId:"EnterOrderModel.reportstoprofs_DDD_L_LBT",
                visibleText:"Macccc Dongle");
```